# Send httpcontent with PostAsync gives Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, api, http-post

To send data as querystring in PostAsync Method, I am using following approach. but i am getting Inernal Server Error.

```
 HttpResponseMessage response;
 string stringContent = "{ 'request_key': 'ABCD1234', 'request_code': 'CODE', 'request_type':'ID_type' }";
using(var client = new HttpClient()) {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SubscriptionUtility.GetConfiguration("BaseURI"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(SubscriptionUtility.GetConfiguration("ContentType")));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", SubscriptionUtility.GetConfiguration("BasicAuthentication"));

                response = await client.PostAsync(SubscriptionUtility.GetConfiguration("SubscriptionAPI"), stringContent, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {

                    var dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestClass>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    //foreach(var d in dataObjects) {

                    //}
                }
            }
```

But When i send the request through fiddler, Its working fine. Here is my fiddler request

User-Agent: Fiddler

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Host: testapi.com

Content-Length: 93

Authorization: Basic 12fbe6e1f63d832aa33232323

**Post Data:**
{
"request_key":"ABCD1234",
"request_code":"CODE",
"request_type":"ID_type"
}

Comment: and what is the trace when not using fiddler?

Comment: fyi basic authorization would be   Authorization:  Basic 12fbe6e1f63d832aa33232323, not token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved the desire functionality using following approach
[Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

```
using(var client = new HttpClient()) {


                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SubscriptionUtility.GetConfiguration("BaseURI"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(SubscriptionUtility.GetConfiguration("ContentType")));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", SubscriptionUtility.GetConfiguration("BasicAuthentication"));
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                       { "request_key", "ABCD1234" },
                       { "request_code", "CODE" },
                       { "request_type", "ID_type" }
                    };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(SubscriptionUtility.GetConfiguration("SubscriptionAPI"), content);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```